# AvalonEdit - Visible Text

Tags: c#, avalonedit

I try to get the visible text of the avalonedit control, but the `VisualLines[]` only handles wordwrap with `TextLines[]` and I dont know how to check if a TextLine is in the visible area or not.

The problem also would be solved if I can get the start- and endoffset (or length) of the visible text in the textview but I didnt find such a function or member...

Can anyone help me? Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `TextView.GetPosition` to retrieve the document position for the corners of the text view:

```
TextViewPosition? start = textView.GetPosition(new Point(0, 0) + textView.ScrollOffset);
TextViewPosition? end = textView.GetPosition(new Point(textView.ActualWidth, textView.ActualHeight) + textView.ScrollOffset);
```

You can use `TextDocument.GetOffset` to convert a TextViewPosition into an offset. Note that you can get back `null` when there is no line at the specified point - within the visible area, that should occur only if the end of the visible area is behind the end of the document, so you should be able to assume the end of the document in those cases:

```
int startOffset = start != null ? document.GetOffset(start.Value.Location) : document.TextLength;
int endOffset = end != null ? document.GetOffset(end.Value.Location) : document.TextLength;
```

However, if you want to, you can also work directly with the VisualLine/TextLines: `VisualLine.VisualTop` tells you where a visual line starts (Y coordinate), and every TextLine within the VisualLine has a `Height` property. Using these, you can determine which text lines are visible, then use their `GetCharacterHitFromDistance` method to retrieve a visual column, and use `VisualLine.GetRelativeOffset` to calculate the text offset from the visual column. (this is what the `TextView.GetPosition` method is doing)

Comment: Aweseome! Now my spellchecker works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: As a personal reference, here is a link to the current reference page for `TextView.GetPosition` in AvalonEdit documentation: http://avalonedit.net/documentation/html/070c6779-a358-33f0-09f4-7a3b49d36ee7.htm